# How to determine if the error was a deadlock?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, deadlock, java

The following transaction has been selected as a victim of a deadlock:

```
public void side2() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
    TestConnectionPool connectionPool = new TestConnectionPool();
    try(Connection connection = connectionPool.get()){
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try {
            PreparedStatement update1 = connection.prepareStatement("update t2 set j=j-1");
            update1.execute();
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
            PreparedStatement update2 = connection.prepareStatement("update t1 set j=j-1");
            update2.execute();
            connection.commit();
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("ex.getErrorCode()=" + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("ex.getSQLState()=" + ex.getSQLState());
            connection.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
            /*
     ex.getErrorCode()=60
     ex.getSQLState()=61000
             */
```

What should I use to determine whether the error is a deadlock: error code, SQL State, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `ex.getErroCode()` has returned `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource` which is deadlock error. Add `ORA` in front of the returned error code then search online or use Oracle supplied tool `oerr` as demonstrated below to determine the error details.

> An error code. This is an integer value identifying the error that caused the `SQLException` instance to be thrown. Its value and meaning are implementation-specific and might be the actual error code returned by the underlying data source. Retrieve the error by calling the method `SQLException.getErrorCode`.[More...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html)

> `[oracle@orcl trace]$ oerr ora 60`
>
> #### 00060, 00000, "deadlock detected while waiting for resource"
>
> **Cause:**  Transactions deadlocked one another while waiting for resources.
>
> **Action:** Look at the trace file to see the transactions and resources
>            involved. Retry if necessary.